# Exercise in C with loop statements: Write code to reverse numbers with do-while statement

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while, do-loops

I have a task (currently studying the loop statement so I'm in the beginner phase)that asks to make a program to reverse an integer number so it must have the  `do`  statement .

The output should be (example):

```
Enter a number: 4568
The reversal is: 8654
```

Please put in mind that since I'm following my book so far I've studied and know the very basics + selection and loop statements. I have very limited choices so *no* arrays.

The book suggests to make a do loop to divide repeatedly the number by  `10`  until it reaches  `0`  this is what I did so far (code not completed) :

```
int main(void)
{
  int n,x;

  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("The reversal is: ");

  x = n % 10;

  printf("%d",x); /*outputs the last number digit in the first place*/ 

  do{



   ....
   n  /= 10;   /* for example if I divide the number 56222  by ten the output would come out as 
               5622 562 56 5*/
   ....

  }while (n!=0);



  return 0;
}
```

I found a way to put the last digit in the  first place as you can see but
I'm struggling to figure out how to reverse the rest of the numbers after dividing the number by 10 repeadetly with this very limited choices.

What should I put in the do statement?
Many thanks in advance .

Comment: You know how to print the last digit (mod 10). And you know how to remove the last digit (divide by 10). So, when you print the last digit, then remove the last digit, the new last digit will be the the second-to-last digit, the one you want to print next. You have all the required tools, so just print it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void)
{
      
    int n,x;
    
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("The reversal is: ");
    
    int rev = 0;     
    
    do{
      
        x = n % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + x; 
        n  /= 10;
    
    }while (n!=0);
    
    printf ("%d", rev);
 
    return 0;
    
}
```

> here you need a new integer rev whose value is 0 initially. Lets take
> example of 432
>
> n = 432
>
> when you do x = n % 10 x = 2
>
> so when you do rev = rev * 10 + x rev is 0 and value of rev will be 2
>
> n /= 10 make n = 43
>
> -->so in the next iteration
>
> n = 43
> x = n % 10 results in x = 3
>
> rev value now is 2
>
> so rev = rev * 10 + x results in 2 * 10 + 3
>
> so rev = 23
>
> n /= 10 results in n = 4
>
> -->in the last iteration   n = 4
> x = n % 10 results in x = 4     rev value now is 23
>
> so rev = rev * 10 + x results in 23 * 10 + 4 so rev = 234
>
> n /= 10 results in n = 0
>
> so when you print rev you get the answer 234 reverse of 432